# Deploy of a Windows Service project by manually copying files

Tags: c#, windows-services, installutil

I have a windows service project in Visual Studio that I inherited from another developer, and I'm struggling to deploy the service to our server.
Is it possible to copy the build files from the Release folder to the server, and then run installutil on the exe?

I've tried it, and although the service install successfully, I'm getting an error 1053 when I start the service that

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a
>   timely fashion

Or is a setup project the only way to go?

Comment: Definitely it may be done by hand then you should investigate the issue. That said a setup is more often than not the way to go for your own sanity...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to install a service some way other than an install utility, you can copy the output of the release folder of a windows service project to a directory and register the service using a [Powershell command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service).